# Error on IE8 initialisation (ordinal 650 not founded in iertutil.dll)

Tags: internet-explorer-8

Any ideas why after upgrade from IE7 to IE8 RC1 I may got:
'The ordinal 650 could not be located in the dynamic link library iertutil.dll.' error?

Comment: not really a programming question.  This would be good for the IT Pros site when it launches.

Answer (score 2):

Check if IE8 was correctly installed. Go to Help, About IE and check version.
In my case, having downloaded IE8, the version which appeared installed was IE7.

Another point: The error message always appeared after Windows had downloaded the following update: Microsoft.NET Framework 3.5 and Microsoft.NET Framework 3.5 Family Update (KB951847).
If your system downloaded the above referenced update, try a System Restore. It's good for a short term solution.

Take note that Microsoft has a toll-free and Free of charge help line for IE8 and only IE8. You may want to give them a try. Toll-free number: 1-866-876-4926 (US and Canada only)

Good Luck,

Vinicio

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely unbearable how they release IE8 , my solution in this case was just downgrade to IE7 not the solution really but worked.

Answer (score 0):

guys it means the IE8 regestry is missing look online for it